# HTML Object Data file if not found

Tags: javascript, html, object, http-status-code-404

Such as below

```
<object type="text/html" data="a.html">

</object>
```

if the file `a.html` doesn't exist, it shows blank. Can I make it lead to another file or show a text saying that `a.html` not found just like *404*?

Comment: Thank you so much. But I just realized a very simple way to do so. That is adding the text I want between the object tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to fetch file using AJAX, check whether it exists and depending on it create `object` with fetched contents or place some message in case of error:

```
$.get('a.html').
    done(function(data) {
        $('body').append('<object type="text/html" data="a.html"></object>');
    }).
    fail(function() {
        $('body').append("<div>file a.html doesn't exist</div>");
    });
```

**NOTE**:

1. Since `a.html` will be cached by browser it will not perform another roundtrip to load object content, but will take it from cache.
2. This will work only if your `a.html` is share the same origin (protocol, host, port) as you original page, or server of `a.thml` sends special HTTP headers for cross origin requests

Answer (score -1):

Well, I know w3schools isn't the most popular reference source, but [they say](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) that the  tag supports the Event Attributes in HTML, which includes the onerror event.

So, you should be able to do this:

```
<object type="text/html" data="a.html" onerror=function() { alert('"a.html" not found'); }>
</object>
```

**EDIT** Finding the proof on MDN is a bit tougher, it takes three links.  [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement) says that object is an HTMLElement, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) says that HTMLElements inherit all GlobalEventHandlers, and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers) includes onerror as a globalEventHandler event.

Comment: Sorry. Tested this, and it didn't work. The data="" returns a 404, but no onError handler is triggered